# How to access the data from streaming query?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

```
cpLocation = "/mnt/data/temp/streamflight"
deltastream = (df.writeStream
               .format("delta")
               .option("checkpointLocation", f"{cpLocation}/_checkpoint")
               .trigger(once=True)
           .start(cpLocation))
```

How to access data from "deltastream" which is of type `pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery` ?

or

How to convert `pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery` to dataframe?